# React: state not firing return

Tags: reactjs

This is the component:

```
import React from 'react';
const ContactCard = ({contact, onFormSubmit}) => {

    this.state = {modal: 'block'};

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        onFormSubmit(contact);
    };

    const showModal = (e) => {
        if (this.state.modal === 'block') {
            this.state.modal = 'none';
        } else {
            this.state.modal = 'block';
        }
        console.log(this.state.modal);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" onClick={handleSubmit} />
            <div>
                <button onClick={showModal}>Open Modal</button>
                <div style={ { display: this.state.modal } }>
                    <h2>The text</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="clearfix"></div>
        </div >
    )
}

export default ContactCard;
```

What is happening is that when I click the button, `showModal` get triggered, which is correct. But the `style={{display: this.state.modal}}` is not changing to `block` or `none`. What is wrong here?

Comment: You don't assign a value to the state directly. You should use `this.setState({ 'modal': 'block' })` as opposed `this.state.modal='block'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are accessing state and modifying it so you need to change your functional component to react class component like below. Also you need to modify the state and to do that you need to use setState so that updated value will be rendered. seState is a method to modify state value and whenever you do setState your component will render once per setState.

If you modify state like this.state.modal = 'block'; it won’t show the modified value and this is not recommended

```
import React from 'react';
class ContactCard extends React.Component{

constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state = {modal: 'block'}
}

showModal = e => {
    const { modal } = this.state;
    if (modal == 'block') {
        this.setState({modal: 'none'}, ()=> {
            console.log(modal);//this will print none here
        });

    } else {
        this.setState({modal : 'block'}, () => {
            console.log(modal);//this will print block here
        });
    }
};

render(){
 const { modal } = this.state;
 return (
    <div>
        <div>
            <button onClick={this.showModal}>Open Modal</button>
            <div style={ { display: modal } }>
                <h2>The text</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="clearfix"></div>
    </div >
  )
 }
}

  export default ContactCard;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `setState` method when you want to update your state, never directly set your state as `this.state.something == ...`. So,

```
const showModal = e => {
  if (this.state.modal === "block") {
    this.setState({ modal: "none" });
  } else {
    this.setState({ modal: "block" });
  }
};
```

Also, do not log your state immediately like this, since it is async. You can't see the updates state like that. There is a callback function for `setState` but you can log your state in your render method easily.

```
render(){
    console.log( this.state.modal );
    return( ... );
}
```

I haven't noticed in the first time buy your component is a functional one, so you can't use `this.state` there. Just define it as a class one.

```
class ContactCard extends React.Component {
  state = { modal: "block" };

  showModal = () => {
    if ( this.state.modal === "block" ) {
      this.setState({ modal: "none" });
    } else {
      this.setState({ modal: "block" });
    }
  };

  render() {
    console.log( this.state.modal );
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.showModal}>Open Modal</button>
          <div style={{ display: this.state.modal }}>
            <h2>The text</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="clearfix" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ContactCard;
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: _this.setState is not a function` is what I get :(

Comment: Define your component as a class component. Also, you are using class fields, so you don't need to define your state like `this.state`, just skip this there and go with `state = { modal: "block"}`

Comment: Lol, a downvote. One can say to improve my answer instead of downvoting it. Since my first part of the answer solves a problem. Helping SO is hard nowadays. @AmazingDayToday, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You've created a functional component. Functional components don't have access to state.

I would recommend reading this guide from section 4 to 5: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

A second problem is that you're attempting to set state directly via assignment.

```
this.state.modal === 'block' . // Incorrect
```

You should use `this.setState({ modal: 'block' })` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Well
1.) data in react is stored in state which is only accessible in class based component, make sure whenever you require state in a component make that component class based.
2.) Never directly mutate state, setState method is used for that.
3.) Never directly mutate arrays,objects as well since these are reference types.